# Amadeus API classifications and Its Soap Client

Tags: amadeus

When I checked the https://sandbox.amadeus.com/ it's showing the JSON APIs and from my research Amadeus provides the XML based Soap API.

So, I need more clarification as to what is sandbox.amadeus.com if its not a regular API? Why is it in JSON and not in XML?

And after having production API keys, can I use JSON services like this for booking or do I have to port it to SOAP XML for that?

Why is the sandbox API in JSON and regular live API is in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I need more clarification as to what is sandbox.amadeus.com if its not a regular API? Why is it in JSON and not in XML?

The sandbox site is an exploratory site really. Amadeus API (it's actually web services) in production is currently only SOAP XML. Amadeus are developing JSON services which can be used in the future, however, as far as I am aware there is no actual date for when this would be available in a production environment.

> And after having production API keys, can I use JSON services like this for booking or do I have to port it to SOAP XML for that?

Only SOAP XML will work at the moment.

> Why is the sandbox API in JSON and regular live API is in XML?

See my answer to your first question